# LWUIT Gui builder

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

I installed JDK 7 and tried running the LWUIT resource editor but it doesn't have the GUI builder tab and the web start version is completely not working, does this mean i have to use an older version of the JDK

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/p/installing-latest-and-greatest-resource.html) for the webstart version.
Only [version 1.5](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2011/08/lwuit-15-released-finally.html) includes the GUI builder.

Comment: thanks man, i only had version 1.4 and the webstart version was not working. Great work with LWUIT its a great resource

Comment: Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist.

Comment: This was a pretty old post and I am no longer the maintainer of that blog or LWUIT. Unfortunately LWUIT seems to be dead and unmaintained and both founders (myself and Chen) moved to Codename One which works out of the box.